# Move Panda Dataframe Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a question about my panda dataframe. I need to move my dataframe to 3 columns to the right to add a logo like:

[image]

As you can see, I want to move my dataframe to have my logo before my df.
This is a part of my code :

```
       # 3- Transform the data
```

And I can't move each column one by one because I have a lot of columns.

Can you help me?

Thanks a lot

Comment: This is not a `pandas` question

Comment: Yes it is a pandas question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can position the dataframe using `to_excel()` parameters, like this:

```py
df_final.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=6, startcol=3)
```

Note, some people add logos to the header of the worksheet (with a suitable margin), as shown in [this XlsxWriter example](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_headers_footers.html), to avoid issues like this.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works, but i can't put the startrow to 0 so i have a space in the first line...

Comment: I don't understand. What is the issue that you are having?

Answer (score 0):

insert 3 columns in the beginning. That'll move the rest to the right

```
df_final.insert(0,'name_of_column1','')
df_final.insert(0,'name_of_column2','')
df_final.insert(0,'name_of_column3','')
```

Comment: It doesn't work because i still have the index in the first column. And I tried to replace 'name_of_column1/2/3' by an empty column but i have an error : "cannot insert , already exists"

Answer (score 0):

You may create a empty column (with empty string name) and make it the first 3 columns. You may also set `index=False` everytime you use `to_excel` to avoid the index to show in the first column.

```
df_final.loc[:, ''] = ''
df_final.reindex([''] * 3 + df_final.columns.drop('').to_list(), axis=1)
df_final.to_excel(path_sub_domain, index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer but i have this error : " [' '] not found in axis"